# How to get the base type of a reference?

Tags: c++, types, reference, c++17

Assuming I have a type `T` of the form `(const) U &`. What is the best way to "extract" `U` from `T`? (Optimally, it should also work if `T` was a lvalue reference).

Comment: You mean something like [`std::remove_reference`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_reference)?

Comment: And [`std::remove_const`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_cv)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thank you, that's exactly what I wanted!

Comment: Or a combination of  both [`std::remove_cvref`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_cvref)